# Wrong values during a Do-While loop C++

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I'm having some trouble during a do-while loop on my code.
It's about an interface class that makes a validation about the values that are typed by the user. I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

```
int Interface::requestOption(){
int option; //El problema está aquí
do{
    cout<<"--------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Type an option...";
    cin>>option;
    if(option<1 || option>8){
        cout<<"Invalid value, type again "<<endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");
        menu();
    }
}while(!(option>0 && option<9));
return option;
```

}

If I use the method for the first time, it returns the value that I actually typed. But when I call it again, while I debug, I notice that the value of option is -893453, and also, it doesn't allow me to type another number (cin >> option is not working).

The method is being called to interact within the next method:

```
void Control::studentsControl(){
int op;
do{
    system("cls");
    interEst->menu();
    op = interEst->requestOption();
    Lista<Students>* students= NULL;
    students = U->getStudents();
    switch(op){

    //Eight options
   //The 8th option is to return to the previous menu.

}while(op != 8);
```

}

Comment: What was the actual input? You probably need to call `cin.clear()` if the stream was set into fail state, because of an invalid input.

Comment: Simplified version works in my hands when printing the actual value of `option` after `"Invalid value"` (btw it is a good idea to tell the user what the invalid value was!). Took out Sleep(), system(), menu() invocations. The usual questions: "which platform, which compiler?" also apply.

Comment: I have edited the question so you can see in which context the method is being called. @user465139

Answer (score 1):

Call `std::cin.clear()` after each iteration before enter new value.

Answer (score 0):

`!(option>0 && option<9)` is `True` for `-893453` `!(False && True) == !False == True`. why not use `(option<1 || option>8)` like in the if statement?